# PHP - substr() bug or invalid argument

Tags: php, json, string, substr

I working at PHP Project With PHP Version 7.0.13

I was dealing with JSON lately, I have a JSON file that needs to be decode to PHP but **before** I decode the JSON, I need to **clean** some abstract string inside the file that JSON obtained inside, to clean the string using `substr()` to get the JSON.

when i write the code, like this:

```
$jsonraw = "\"{ JSON should be here, later }\"";
$cutstart = strpos($jsonraw, "{");
$cutend = strrpos($jsonraw, "\"");
$jsonclean = substr($jsonraw, $cutstart, $cutend);
echo $jsonclean;
```

The output is like this

> { JSON should be here, later }

But when the string is like this

```
$jsonraw = "\"some abstract string to remove { JSON should be here, later }\"";
```

The output is became like this

> { JSON should be here, later }"

As we can see there was a quote symbol `"` at the last of the string, I was trying to decrement the `$cutend`, like this `$jsonclean = substr($jsonraw, $cutstart, --$cutend);` and this to `$cutend-1`

Any help, I appreciate.
Sorry for my bad English

Comment: use `rtrim()` to remove last `"`

Comment: @Dr.Strange yeah, but that doesn't explain the behavior.

Comment: The third parameter of `substr()` is the length of the string and not the end position.

Comment: Using `$cutend-1` its work so what was the issue @NigelRen

Comment: @Dr.Strange thanks it works..

Comment: @Dr.Strange using `$cutend-1` the `"` symbol is still there..

Comment: @Nigel so.. `substr($jsonraw, $cutstart, $cutend-$cutstart)` is the valid one? to get the targeted string that i want?

Comment: That's what I've put in my answer below.  BUT as I say, beware that quotes and { } may occur in json strings all over the place.

Comment: @Nigal i know.. `strrpos()` is enough to get the last `"` symbols, and thanks for the advice..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the third parameter is the length of the string, you need to say that the length is the end position minus the start position...

```
$jsonclean = substr($jsonraw, $cutstart, $cutend-$cutstart);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `preg_match` to get the json from that string:

```
$string = "some abstract string to remove { JSON should be here, later }";

preg_match('/\{.*\}/', $string, $match);

var_dump($match[0]);
```

the result would be:

```
string(30) "{ JSON should be here, later }"
```

Comment: can you explain what inside $match?

Comment: you can var_dump the variable to see what it holds.. The first item in that returned array is the valid json you need